# Adding a single item to multiple categories

Tags: list, document-library

I've grouped some documents in several categories (of a document library) but I want some documents to show up in multiple categories without having to re-upload the document. How can I do this?

Comment: Simply make the Category column multi-select... If its a Lookup field you can check Allow multiple values option from Lookup column properties! Can you tell us how are categories used?

Comment: multiple value fields cannot be used to group or filter data in list views, though.

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? We have a similar requirement. and as you know, category column doesn't allow the users to select "allow multiple selection". Thank you,
Richards.

Comment: How did you solve this problem? I am searching a solution